# Throw exception and continue work after returning http response

Tags: spring-boot, rest, kotlin, exception

Is there a way to throw an exception, return http response status and continue work?

Currently I just throw an exception, handle it with `@RestControllerAdvice` like this:

```
@ExceptionHandler(
        EntityNotFoundException::class,
    )
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY)
    fun handleBonusNotFound(ex: Exception): ResponseEntity<Any> {
        val errorId = UUID.randomUUID().toString()
        logger.error("errorId: $errorId, msg: '${ex.message}'", ex)

        return ResponseEntity.unprocessableEntity().body(
            ErrorModelResponse(errorId, ex.message.toString())
        )
    }
```

and of course no code after the exception throwing works, which is something that I need to fix, basically all I need is to return 422 response status, and continue work, but how do I do this, while keeping most of my logic in service, and still return 422 response in `@RestController`?

Maybe I need to fake some kind of exception or maybe there is already some tools to do this?

Any help appreciated!

Comment: I don't understand.  Either code throws an Exception (and the executing thread follows that path) or you do not throw an Exception.  What do you mean, continuing work - do you mean asynchronously?   Perhaps you want to process the request despite returning 422 ("Unprocessable Entity"), in which case you need to create a new Thread and start it before returning the 422.  Is that what you want to know how to do?

Comment: @AndrewL yes, I don't necessarily need to throw an exception, if I would be able to return 422 and still process the request, it would be just fine 

also note that all logic written in suspend functions

Answer (score 0):

Here is working code a little like what you want.
If the user specifies a channel_id then the service will execute quickly so the response is synchronous.  But if the user specified no channel_id then the service will do something over a much larger set of data.  The caller then has the option to receive a response immediately (`async==true`) or wait.  You can see in this code how I "continue processing" whilst returning an immediate response, by the use of a simple old `Thread`.  Of course you could adapt to use Coroutines/etc.

```
    @PostMapping(value = ["/channel/resetmeta"])
    fun createChannel(
        @RequestParam(name = "channel_id") channelId: RULID?,
        @RequestParam async: Boolean? = false,
        requestingUser: Profile?
    ): ResponseEntity<Any> {
        requireValidProfile(requestingUser)

        return if (channelId != null) {
            val response = channelService.rebuildChannelMetaData(channelId, requestingUser)
            if(response.changed)  ResponseEntity.ok(response.channel)
            else ResponseEntity<Any>(response.channel, HttpStatus.NOT_MODIFIED)
        } else {
            if(async==true) {
                Thread() {
                    channelService.rebuildAllChannelMetaData(requestingUser)
                }.start()
                ResponseEntity(HttpStatus.ACCEPTED)
            }
            else ResponseEntity.ok(channelService.rebuildAllChannelMetaData(requestingUser))
        }
    }
```

---

**EDIT**

OP said:

> Looks good, but is there a way to return response based on what happened inside the thread? I need to return 422 if one of processing entities was problematic and 204 if everything went fine

I think I have misunderstood when you said "continue work" I took it to mean that you wanted to return some response to the user whilst (long-running) work happens.  If you do not want to return control **until** you have either a successful or unsuccessful outcome, then this is easy.  There are two ways:

1. All in one place Exception handling

```
@PostMapping(value = ["/channel"], consumes = [MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE])
fun createChannel(@RequestBody channelCreationRequest: ChannelCreationRequest):
        ResponseEntity<Channel> {
    try {
        return ResponseEntity
            .status(HttpStatus.CREATED)
            .body(channelService.createChannel(channelCreationRequest))
    } catch (ex: EntityNotFoundException) {
        val errorId = UUID.randomUUID().toString()
        logger.error("errorId: $errorId, msg: '${ex.message}'", ex)
        return ResponseEntity.unprocessableEntity().body(
            ErrorModelResponse(errorId, ex.message.toString())
        )
    }
}
```

2. Use a separate `ExceptionHandler` and keep your happy path clean of Exception handling:

```
@PostMapping(value = ["/channel"], consumes = [MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE])
fun createChannel(@RequestBody channelCreationRequest: ChannelCreationRequest):
        ResponseEntity<Channel> {
        return ResponseEntity
            .status(HttpStatus.CREATED)
            .body(channelService.createChannel(channelCreationRequest))
}

@ExceptionHandler(EntityNotFoundException::class)
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY)
fun handleBonusNotFound(ex: Exception): ResponseEntity<Any> {
    val errorId = UUID.randomUUID().toString()
    logger.error("errorId: $errorId, msg: '${ex.message}'", ex)

    return ResponseEntity.unprocessableEntity().body(
        ErrorModelResponse(errorId, ex.message.toString())
    )
}
```

Comment: Looks good, but is there a way to return response based on what happened inside the thread? I need to return 422 if one of processing entities was problematic and 204 if everything went fine